# F# open namespace error

Tags: .net, f#

I setup a windows 2012 r2 box with .net 4.5.2 installed. Then I install tsunami ide and copy the latest FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll to this box.

After `r @"c:\o\FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll`

and there is a createFile exception after

```
open FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom
```

Could anyone help?

```
> open FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom ;;

> 
error FS0192: internal error: CreateFile(0x80070002)
Stack Trace
System.Exception: CreateFile(0x80070002)

   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@598.Invoke(String message)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.go@523-3[b,c,d](String fmt, Int32 len, FSharpFunc`2 outputChar, FSharpFunc`2 outa, b os, FSharpFunc`2 finalize, FSharpList`1 args, Int32 i)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.run@521[b,c,d](FSharpFunc`2 initialize, String fmt, Int32 len, FSharpList`1 args)    
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Reflect.Invoke@720-4.Invoke(T1 inp)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILBinaryReader.MemoryMappedFile.Create(String fileName)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILBinaryReader.MMapChannel.OpenIn(String f)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILBinaryReader.OpenILModuleReader(String infile, ILReaderOptions opts)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Build.AssemblyResolution.get_ILAssemblyRef()    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Build.TryFindByExactILAssemblyRef@3387.Invoke(AssemblyResolution ar)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.TryFind[T](FSharpFunc`2 predicate, FSharpList`1 list)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Build.TcImports.TryFindExistingFullyQualifiedPathFromAssemblyRef(ILAssemblyRef assref)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiEvaluationSession.resolveType[a](a _fsiDynamicCompiler, ILAssemblyRef aref)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.clo@2436-495.Invoke(ILAssemblyRef aref)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.getTRefType(cenv cenv, ILTypeRef tref)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.convTypeSpec(cenv cenv, emEnv emEnv, Boolean preferCreated, ILTypeSpec tspec)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.convTypeAux(cenv cenv, emEnv emEnv, Boolean preferCreated, ILType typ)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.buildTypeDefPass1b@1849.Invoke(ILType typ)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.buildTypeDefPass1b(cenv cenv, FSharpList`1 nesting, emEnv emEnv, ILTypeDef tdef)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.buildModuleFragment@2044.Invoke(ILTypeDef tdef)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.iter[T](FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.buildModuleFragment(cenv cenv, emEnv emEnv, AssemblyBuilder asmB, ModuleBuilder modB, ILModuleDef m)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.AbstractIL.ILRuntimeWriter.emitModuleFragment(ILGlobals ilg, emEnv emEnv, AssemblyBuilder asmB, ModuleBuilder modB, ILModuleDef modul, Boolean debugInfo, FSharpFunc`2 resolvePath)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiDynamicCompiler.ProcessInputs(FsiDynamicCompilerState istate, FSharpList`1 inputs, Boolean showTypes, Boolean isIncrementalFragment, Boolean isInteractiveItExpr, FSharpList`1 prefixPath)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiDynamicCompiler.EvalParsedDefinitions(FsiDynamicCompilerState istate, Boolean showTypes, Boolean isInteractiveItExpr, FSharpList`1 defs)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.clo@1753-486.Invoke(FsiDynamicCompilerState istate)    
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiInteractionProcessor.interactiveCatch[a](FSharpFunc`2 f, a istate)
```

Comment: there seems to be some files missing (or in having an unexpected version) but it's a bit hard to tell where exactly you have issues - maybe add a .config with binding redirects? Or try to find/install the F# runtime (basically look for FSharp.Core.dll and/or try different versions ...)

Comment: The environment doesn't allow to install VS. And we cannot install things like VWD_FSharp.exe. What allowed is to copy required dll files but it is just like what you said...hard to tell where exactly I have issues...